# ProbabilityDistribution with variable number of dimensions

Tags: function-construction, probability-or-statistics, distributions, vector

I would like to construct a ProbabilityDistribution with a variable number of dimensions.  I tried to use `$Assumptions = x ∈ Vectors[d, Reals]` so that the variable `x` would be an unspecified vector with $d$ dimensions.  However, I found that I could not use `{x[[1]], -∞, ∞}` to define the ranges of each element of the vector.

I'm seeking to define a distribution similar to the multivariate T distribution, but want flexibility to modify the definition.  So I like to use `ProbabilityDistribution` for the definition, rather than using a built-in distribution.

My question is what's the best way to define a vector variable, which can be used in `ProbabilityDistribution` as a variable for the range of each dimensions defined?

Comment: Something like: `n = 3;
ProbabilityDistribution[pdf, 
 Sequence @@ Table[{x[i], -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {i, n}]]` ?

Comment: But I think that if you don't want to specify the dimension explicitly, then you'll probably need to do it with `Product`, `Sum`, etc. commands rather than `ProbabilityDistribution`.  But I could certainly be wrong about that.  Others can chime in.  If leaving the dimensions unspecified is necessary, then maybe explaining why that's necessary would help someone make a constructive suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Vector variables are not supported in the Probability & Statistics framework as of now. So the dimensionality needs to be specified.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you JimB, your suggestion worked well.  Use of the Sequence function which strips a layer of lists is part of what I was having difficulty with.  Here is a simple example of a multivariate normal with independent dimensions.

```
n = 3; 
IndMultiNormal = ProbabilityDistribution[
    Exp[-Table[x[i], {i, n}].Table[x[i], {i, n}]], 
    Sequence @@ Table[{x[i], -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {i, n}]
]
```